# Django photologue images and queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset, photologue

I've added photologue to my project, because it does 99% of the things I was trying to achieve by myself.

Now I need to connect the uploaded images and images in galleries to my posts. This is why I've added a ManyToMany field to the photologue Photo model

```
Class ImageModel(models.Model):
     post_images =  models.ManyToManyField(Post, blank=True)
```

And will do the same to the Gallery model

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
     post_gallery =  models.ManyToManyField(Post, blank=True)
```

Now my idea is to be able to add a gallery and/or specific images to my post . Both options should be available.

The queryset I would like to have is to get all the individual images, that are attached to the post and also all the images in the gallery if a gallery is attached. Then to pass and render them to the page in some sort of gallery (Slider, carousel or something else).
I'd like to be able to get them in the template with one for loop, so I think the queryset have to be one.

I have a view that renders the specific page type and I don't know if I should include the queryset and context in this function or to create a new one for the images. And how to do it.

```
def post(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, post_slug=slug)
    context = {
        'post': post,
     }
    return render(request, 'project_name/post.html', context)
```

I hope I have explained what I'd like to do. Django is new to me and querysets are still a bit complex.

Comment: I was able to get all the images on the server with the following query
`images = Photo.objects.all()`

But now I need to get the images that are specific to the page I'm viewing

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you try adding galleriesto posts from posts?

```
from photologue.models import Gallery
class Post(models.Model):
    gallery = models.ManyToManyField(Gallery, blank=True )
```

#Edit ___
@TwinDewey In this case you need to make a query in Views to get the Galleries when showing Post details.

```
galleries = gallery.posts.all() 
gal = [] 
for excercise in excercises: 
    gal.append(Gallery.objects.filter(gallery__name=self.post.title))
```

Or you can make a query and merge it with the Post context using

```
from itertools import chain 
list(chain(post_context,Gallery.objects.filter(gallery__name=self.post.title)))
```

That´s for gallery. Posts would have another query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought about it and yes, this is the logical and correct way to do it. But until recently I was working in a company that develops websites as support and 99% of the people complained that there are too many steps for adding images to a page. That is the reason I wanted to add the "post" field to images and not the other way around.

Comment: ManyToMany fields are symmetric. There is no "other way around". You put them field where it seems most logical from a programmer's view. Users don't factor in. How this is presented in the admin interface, is entirely up to you and doesn't rely on where you put the field.

Comment: @TwinDewey In this case you need to make a query in Views to get the Galleries when showing Post details.

    galleries = gallery.posts.all()
    gal = []
    for excercise in excercises: 
        gal.append(Gallery.objects.filter(gallery__name=self.post.title))

Or you can make a query and merge it with the Post context using

    from itertools import chain
    list(chain(post_context, Gallery.objects.filter(gallery__name=self.post.title))) 

That´s for gallery. Posts would have another query.

Comment: Modified my initial response for better formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use union to group the photos tied to the post itself and inside the gallery. The trick is to get the right models so they are the same objects:

```
from django.db import models
from photologue.models import Gallery, Photo


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    published_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    photos = models.ManyToManyField(Photo, related_name='posts')
    galleries = models.ManyToManyField(Gallery, related_name='posts')

    @property
    def all_images(self):
        # Create a number of querysets that have photos from selected galleries
        # ..note:
        #   .only() is used to trim down on the fields fetched from the database.
        #   .prefetch_related() is used to eliminate extra queries during iteration
        qs = []
        for gallery in self.galleries.prefetch_related('photos').only('photos'):  # type: Gallery
            qs.append(gallery.photos.only('image', 'title'))

        return self.photos.only('image', 'title').union(*qs)
```

Now you can use it in a template like so:

```html
{% for photo in post.all_images %}
    <img src="{{ photo.image.url }}" alt="{{ photo.title }}" />
{% endfor %}
```